# I need to find out the true lyrics of "The Rover - Led Zeppelin"

Tags: lyrics

It is one of the most famous songs from last century. The problem is that we don't have good lyrics for it, partially because this song was never played live. We only have a few versions of it, the most famous of course being the one from Physical Graffiti, which should be our reference I guess.

I will copy the most famous lyrics you can find on Google and point out the troublesome parts of it:

> I've been to London, seen seven wonders I know to trip is just to fall
> I used to rock it, sometimes I'd roll it
> I always knew what it was for
> There can be no denying, that the wind'll shake 'em down
> **And the flat world's flying, and there's a new plague on the land**
> **Traversed the planet**, when heaven sent me
> I saw the kings who rule them all
> Still by the firelight and purple moonlight I hear the rested rivers call
> And the wind is crying, from a love that won't grow cold
> My lover, she is lying, on the dark side of the globe
> You got me rocking when I ought to be a-rolling
> Darling, tell me, darling, which way to go
> You keep me rocking, baby, then you keep me stolen
> Won't you tell me, darling, which way to go, that's right
> Oh how I wonder, oh how I worry, and I would dearly like to know
> I've all this wonder, of earthly plunder, will it leave us anything to show
> And our time is flying, see the candle burning low
> Is the new world rising, from the shambles of the old\

The confusion lies in the bold parts of the song.

Some people would say that "and the flat world's flying" really is "and the flat world's dying" which would slightly make more sense, given that it is wildy accepted that this song is about a ship from 1800 but I can clearly hear an "L" sound when Robert Plant sings this line. The problem is that "and the flat world is flying" doesn't really make sense as a sentence.

Another people suggest that "and the flat world is flying" really is "and the flag we're flying" which does sound more fitting to what I listen and makes much more sense as a sentence. In this version the (first) bold line of the lyrics above become:

> And the flag we're flying is the new flag of the land.

I would like native english speakers to tell me if this line can be the correct one, because it sounds to me that the word "on" is more fitting than "of" in that line that Plant sings.

About the "Traversed the planet", I searched the pronounciation of "traversed" and it seems impossible for me that Plant sings that word in this music. The alternative phrase for that would be "in fields aplenty", which would sound more correct to me.

link to the alternative lyrics [here](https://som13.com.br/led-zeppelin/the-rover)

EDIT: I've found a website from a guy who made a deep research on ALL of Led Zeppelin's lyrics and all my doubts about this band are solved.

Comment: "It is one of the most famous songs from last century" Err... I think it probably doesn't make it to top 30 of the most famous Zeppelin songs alone? As for picking up what Plant is singing it was never easy, native English or not :) I think this would have to be answered with some sources or references, not by listening. Or before you know it, we'll be listening to Stairway to Heaven backwards.

Comment: so english is a language that can't be used for speaking, just for reading? Sorry, I'm not sure why would you waste your time posting a comment like that. Do you receive points for doing this?

Comment: As in, if the lyrics aren't clear and people hear subjective things, you can only get people's subjective opinions as an answer.

Comment: He's definitely talking about a flag.  The other line I've seen as "It fills the planet", neither that nor "Traversed the planet" really makes much sense.

Comment: I believe what Amarth meant is [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) where sometimes it's difficult to decipher the lyric due to how it's pronounced/sung.

Comment: @AndrewT. very rare to happen as the artists almost never publish their lyrics but the listeners do the work of writting it down. Anyways, I found the correct version already and it is about flying a flag